# Android app with parce.com.No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-activity

There is my code.The problem is that when i change the orientation i got sucha line : No adapter attached; skipping layout.Marked with red colour.But after some miliseconds layout is attached.So i whant to know is it ok,or il should change my code somehow?

```
package by.test.roma.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager manager;
    List<Recipe> recipes;
    static int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        if(count == 0) {
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
            Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key");
            count++;
        }
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Recipes");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> recipesList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + recipesList.size() + " recipes");
                    for(ParseObject obj :recipesList) {
                       initializeData(obj);
                }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                initializeAdapter();
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        //initializeData();



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void initializeAdapter(){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(recipes);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void initializeData(ParseObject obj){
        recipes.add(new Recipe(obj.getString("Description"), obj.getString("shortDescription"), obj.getString("Name"), R.drawable.share));
        Log.d("score", Integer.toString(recipes.size()));
    }
}



My log : 
08-28 14:04:28.913  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Fri May  4 10:32:42 KST 2012
08-28 14:04:28.948  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-28 14:04:28.948  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-28 14:04:28.983  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-28 14:04:29.058  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/CLIPBOARD﹕ Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
08-28 14:04:29.573  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/score﹕ Retrieved 2 recipes
08-28 14:04:29.573  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/score﹕ 1
08-28 14:04:29.573  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/score﹕ 2
08-28 14:04:29.603  14256-14257/by.test.roma.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 299K, 8% free 13141K/14215K, paused 2ms+2ms
08-28 14:04:29.618  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 8% free 13239K/14343K, paused 13ms
08-28 14:04:29.618  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 14.041MB for 417616-byte allocation
08-28 14:04:29.633  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 13646K/14791K, paused 13ms
08-28 14:04:43.178  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
08-28 14:04:43.418  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-28 14:04:43.428  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
08-28 14:04:43.578  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/score﹕ Retrieved 2 recipes
08-28 14:04:43.578  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/score﹕ 1
08-28 14:04:43.578  14256-14256/by.test.roma.myapplication D/score﹕ 2
.
.
.
```

Comment: You probably saw already that it will work the way you have it set up. But you can solve this by initializing an adapter with an empty list and attaching it to the recyclerview in onCreate. Then instead of `new RVAdapter(recipes)` you can call a setter inside the adapter that will fill it with the items - `RVAdapter.setItems(recipes)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and set your adapter for the RecyclerView to be drawn:

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    // initialize your array and set an adapter even if its empty to avoid the 
    // skipping layout warning
    recipes = new ArrayList<>();
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(recipes);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then once you fetch and add your data:

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or the more efficient:

```
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(positionOfItem);
```